# Word 2010 - Registry Key for AutoCorrect Options

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-word-2010

Microsoft states in the below mentioned article that there is a Registry Key for AutoCorrect settings in Word 2010:

> [How to reset user options and registry settings in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822005)
>
> - AutoCorrect settings (correct two initial capitals, capitalize names of days, replace text as you type)
> - AutoCorrect settings used only by Word (corrects accidental usage of CAPS LOCK key, capitalizes first letter of sentences)

I search for the registry-key. I already found the registry-keys for Excel, PowerPoint and Outlook (see below). Can you please help me with the key(s) for Word 2010?

Keys apply to AutoCorrect-Options of PowerPoint and Excel:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\AutoCorrect]`

- `ACOptions  (DWORD) 00000000` *(Show AutoCorrectOptions: this key affects also Word, the other keys do not affect Word)*
- `CorrectTwoInitialCapitals (DWORD) 00000000` *(Correct two initial capitals)*

Key applies to AutoCorrect-Options of Outlook:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options]

- `WordMailACOptions (HEX) 00,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,\
  01,00,01,00,01,00,01,01,01,00,00,00,01,01,00,01,00,02,00,03,01,03,01,03,01,\
  03,00,03,01,02,00,03,01,03,01,03,01,03,01,00,00,27,01`

Answer (score 1):

Those keys apply to Excel, PowerPoint and Access, I think, since the equivalent group policy settings do.

There are group policy settings for these in Word, I can only assume this is because people may want different settings for 'real' word processing than the bits of text editing in the rest of Office.

There don't seem to be any equivalent "non-policy" keys The equivalent paths to policy settings are below, but it would be easier to set these through domain or local security policies than through registry changes.

**Correct TWo INitial CApitals**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fTwoInitialCaps_24_1
```

**Capitalize first letter of sentence**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fInitialCap_32_1
```

**Capitalize names of days**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCapDayNames_48_1
```

**Correct accidental usage of cAPS LOCK key**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCapsLock_40_1
```

**Replace text as you type**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCorrectTyping_16_1
```

**Correct keyboard setting**

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCorrectkeyboard_64_1
```

Comment: I don't have an assist sub-Folder under `...word\Options` (even after using the GUI to change the settings)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed the default settings, there may not be any registry key for the Word AutoCorrect options.

Why not just change the settings you need from the [Word Options Proofing menu](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291473) - no need to hack the registry?

Comment: Because if you have to do it each time you go to a new Installation/PC you want to run a script that automatically configures the PC as you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Word captures the  Spelling and Grammer settings in a .dic file under

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof

the file CUSTOM.dic