# Registry key settings auto correct Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

We have a medium size network and like to set autocorrect options in Word 2010 with a group policy.

I found these [settings in an earlier question:](https://superuser.com/questions/335096/word-2010-registry-key-for-autocorrect-options)

> Correct TWo INitial CApitals
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fTwoInitialCaps_24_1
> ```
>
> Correct TWo INitial CApitals
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fTwoInitialCaps_24_1
> ```
>
> Capitalize first letter of sentence
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fInitialCap_32_1
> ```
>
> Capitalize names of days
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCapDayNames_48_1
> ```
>
> Correct accidental usage of cAPS LOCK key
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCapsLock_40_1
> ```
>
> Replace text as you type
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCorrectTyping_16_1
> ```
>
> Correct keyboard setting
>
> ```
> software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\word\options\assist\fCorrectkeyboard_64_1
> ```

When I apply the keys mentioned above everything is under control except one setting and thats:

> Capitalize first letter of table cells**

Does anyone know with which key this auto correct option can be controlled in Word 2010?

Answer (score 1):

All these settings are stored in one big registry entry (binary):
"**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Data:Settings**".

By analysing the special registry value names ({Name}_{Number}_1) I found out, that the first number points to a position of a range in this byte array.

So first I changed the known options separatly and later *Capitalize first letter of table cells* in the word menu and checked the **Settings**-Value after each step: every time one byte changed from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1.

With a simple calculation I got the missing registry value name: Something like {Name}_232_1 will change the settings *Capitalize first letter of table cells*. The {Name} before is not recognized at all (as I tried with the known settings), so you can call it "**fCapTable_232_1**".